# in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc(), in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc() , in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, kaggle

I tried to analize this code [Titanic Problem link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/livandiogenskiy/start-on-titanic)

And when i launch it on Jupyter notebook it cout me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/305l1.png --- code is 10-th Karnel on first  link ↑

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axVML.png) --- also picture of the code

Comment: Please try to include your code as formatted text and not linked images. That being said, the issue is that you're indexing a column named "1" that isn't there.

Comment: @nathan liang never mind, problem was solved. I would be happy if you will help with my new problem (look last in my profile)